# PyQt styling with css classes fails

Tags: python, css, qt, pyqt, stylesheet

I'm working on a GUI in which i have to display some ToolButtons.
I'm using an external CSS file to style them.
To make it easy i defined a CSS class (with setProperty) and i'm using in the CSS file to change the appearance of the buttons depending on their class.

My Python code looks like this :

```
...
bt = QtGui.QToolButton(parent.qtObject)
bt . setToolButtonStyle ( QtCore.Qt.ToolButtonTextUnderIcon )
bt.setProperty('class','StaticButton')
bt.setStyleSheet(css_content)
...
```

My CSS is like :

```
QToolButton.StaticButton
{
    border: 2px solid #4f4f51;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-size: 10px;
    background-color: qlineargradient(x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1,stop: 0 #e4e4c8, stop: 1 #b9b9a9);
}
```

The problem is that only the background of the button is affected. I tried many alternatives such as `QToolButton[class=StaticButton]` in CSS file or `.StaticButton` only. Both alternatives led to the save behaviour.
If i apply the CSS directly on the button with :

```
bt.setStyleSheet("border: 2px solid #4f4f51;border-radius: 5px;font-size: 10px;background-color: qlineargradient(x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1,stop: 0 #e4e4c8, stop: 1 #b9b9a9);")
```

all works perfectly, but i don't want to have CSS in my python code.

Can someone please tell me what's wrong in my code ? I don't understand why the background property is used but not the others.

Note : i've checked the CSS imported and the file is perfectly valid. I did several tests and each time, only the background property works ... what's happening ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

According to reference sheets setting property will must work, but there has a annoying things. ps: i suffer this problem about one month then admit to defeat.

My solution is about to work around. little bit hacky

```
bt = QToolButton(.)
bt.setObjectName("btStaticxxx") # xxx to any string
```

css;

```
QToolButton#btStatic*   //collapses all ToolButton instances that objectname startswith btStatic
{
.
.
}
```

Comment: Do you mean, we need to use `*` on after the class name in CSS ?

Comment: '_*_' on QToolButton#btStatic* is a wildcard. #btStatic* collapses 'btStaticmybutton' or 'btStatic2'.